# Magic Mouse and Alum keyboard autosleep?

Tags: mac, magic-mouse, wireless-keyboard

Should I manually turn off my aluminum keyboard and magic mouse when my iMac sleeps, or is there an automatic low-power mode?

( BONUS: How often should the batteries be replaced? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse and keyboard sleep automatically.  I've only turned mine off when away for extend periods (e.g. vacation.)  I've seen 5+ months battery life (with fairly light usage) this way.  If it were my primary machine I suspect ~3 months would be good battery life.

Answer (score 1):

As of today my Christmas-present wireless keyboard reports 17% battery remaining on its first set of alkaline batteries.  That extrapolates to 0% at 105 days; it obviously won't run to 0% so reduce that to somewhere between 87 days (today) and 105.

I am not using any other bluetooth devices; there was a battery life issue - for which Apple releaed a wireless-keyboard firmware update - when the wireless keyboard was used with other bluetooth devices.  See:

http://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=search&src=support_site.kbase.search&locale=en_US&q=wireless%20keyboard%20firmware

Answer to your bonus question:  For me, not until they die.  That looks like about 3 months+ of run time for my usage pattern, the updated firmware, and no BT mouse, based on a sample size of 1...

Comment: Your usage pattern is ... ? And, am I supposed to turn it off at when the iMac is off? I just installed the battery life update.

Comment: Probably 8-9 hours a day, not necessarily typing-intensive, but on and active.  I don't shut my keyboard off, ever (except a couple of times, just to watch the reconnect process).  I don't know how much battery run time would be extended if I did, but at 3 months/set of batteries, I'm not motivated to do so.  I suspect the KB goes into a low power mode when it has been idle for a while but that's a guess.

Comment: +1 for first answer. Chris gets the check for an affirmative answer. Funny that your estimates match up.